# Wrong formating of array of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm trying to format an array of object, unfortunately, I'm doing it wrong.

```
sortGroup=(group)=> {
    for (const entry of group.entries) {
     arrayofHeros.push(`Title: ${field(entry, 'Title')},'UserName': ${field(entry, 'UserName')} , Strentgh:  ${field(entry, 'Strentgh')} ,Age: ${field(entry,'Age')} \n`)   
    }
    for (const subGroup of group.groups) {
        sortGroup(subGroup)
    }
}
```

Result when `console.log(arrayofHeros);`

```
 [ 'Title: Avangers: UserName: Wolvering , Strength:  Smash , Age: 28',
      'Title: X-men: UserName: Stryfe, Strength:  Superhuman, Age: 34',
      'Title: X-men: UserName: Lady Deathstrike, Strength:  Cyborg, Age: 27',
 ]
```

Expected Result

```
arrayofHeros = 
[ {
    Title: 'Avangers',
    UserName: 'Wolvering',
    Strength:  'Smash',
    Age: 28
    },
    {
    Title: 'X-men',
    UserName: 'Stryfe',
    Strength:  'Superhuman',
    Age: 34
    },
    {
    Title: 'X-men',
    UserName: 'Lady Deathstrike',
    Strength:  'Cyborg',
    Age: 27,
      },
     ]
```

Comment: Why are you pushing strings into the result array if you want objects?

Comment: Try: `arrayofHeros.push({Title: field(entry, 'Title'),'UserName': field(entry, 'UserName')})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are pushing a string here

```
arrayofHeros.push(`Title: ${field(entry, 'Title')},'UserName': ${field(entry, 'UserName')} , Strentgh:  ${field(entry, 'Strentgh')} ,Age: ${field(entry,'Age')} \n`)
```

you should push an object

```
arrayofHeros.push({
  Title: field(entry, 'Title'),
  UserName: field(entry, 'UserName'),
  Strentgh: field(entry, 'Strentgh'),
  Age: field(entry,'Age')
})
```

Comment: Thank you soo much